# Is it possible and rational to deploy .ova file on the cloud?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine

Is it possible and rational to deploy .ova file on the cloud? Does anybody have a similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ravello to deploy ESXI on the cloud and then you can deploy OVA on top of that ,

see :
https://www.ravellosystems.com/solutions/esxi-cloud/install-esxi-on-aws